# Question sur la nationalité: Français ou française ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs

Comment un homme doit-il écrire correctement sa nationalité dans un formulaire où il faut l'indiquer ?

> Nationalité : Français (substantif)

ou

> Nationalité : française (adjectif)

J'ai rencontré les deux formes.

De plus, j'ai aussi vu la forme *Française* (F majuscule) qui me paraît incorrecte puisque l'adjectif française qualifie le nom *nationalité*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comme l’indique @Romain, si on cherche à compléter le formulaire comme on le ferait pour une phrase, une seule réponse est possible : « Nationalité » est un nom féminin, on accorde donc l’adjectif « française » au féminin.
C’est la réponse la plus logique, qui ne prend pas de majuscule initiale.

Cependant, si l’on considère qu’il faut utiliser la version nominale de ce gentilé, comme si l’on disait   « Je suis un Français », il faudrait accorder le nom avec son sujet, donc avec le sexe de la personne qui parle.
 Une majuscule serait aussi obligatoire.

Comment: C'est tout de même habituel d’utiliser une majuscule en début de phrase, même s'il s'agit d'une réponse qui ne contient qu'un seul mot.

Comment: Sans ponctuation finale, il me paraît difficile de dire que c'est une phrase, et donc de défendre la majuscule initiale. Mais c’est un point de vue qui se défend.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je perçois une nette différence entre une question et un item de formulaire, même si un formulaire est bel et bien une demande d’information. Pour une question, je réponds. Pour un formulaire, j'indique. Mais peut-être n'est-ce qu'une perception personnelle?

Answer (score 1):

Selon moi, la logique voudrait que ce soit "française". "Nationalité" est un mot féminin donc nécessite une réponse au féminin.